# How can I added a ".Tapped += async (s, e) => {. ...." directly to a new TapGestureRecognizer();?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code that I have:

```
        TapGestureRecognizer tap1 = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        .Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, nameof(TapCommand), source: this)
        .Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, nameof(TapCommandParam), source: this);
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap1);

        TapGestureRecognizer tap2 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tap2.Tapped += async (s, e) => {
            this.SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "GridTappedColor");
            await Task.Delay(500);
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Default;
        };
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap2);
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way I can added the following code:

```
        .Tapped += async (s, e) => {. ....
```

Directly to this:

```
        tap2 = new TapGestureRecognizer()
```

Something like this:

```
        TapGestureRecognizer tap2 = new TapGestureRecognizer().Tapped()
```

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I would like to know if it's possible to combine new TapGestureRecognizer() and .Tapped += async (s, e) => {
            this.SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "GridTappedColor");
            await Task.Delay(500);
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Default;
        };

Comment: Something similar to what I am doing here tap1 = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        .Bind(TapGestureRecognizer.  .....

Comment: I think that it's fine as you have it. You are trying to resolve 2 differents things using only one instruction and currently it's not possible. For one hand you're creating the new object and for another hand adding the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to have an extension that lets you do something with the item and return the very same item.

```
public static class TapGestureRecognizerExtensions {
    public static TapGestureRecognizer BindAction( 
         this TapGestureRecognizer recognizer, 
         Action<TapGestureRecognizer> action ) {
             action(recognizer);
             return recognizer;
    }
}

...

TapGestureRecognizer tap2 = 
    new TapGestureRecognizer().BindAction( 
      t =>
        t.Tapped += async (s, e) => {
            this.SetDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, "GridTappedColor");
            await Task.Delay(500);
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Default;
       };
    );
```